# Read from unix socket file

Tags: docker, kotlin, jnr

I'm trying to read some lines (or just something) from /var/run/docker.sock.
Basically I'm trying to convert the following into code.

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/events
```

I'm using the jnr.unixsocket library and my code is as follows

```
val socketAddress = UnixSocketAddress(File("/var/run/docker.sock"))
val socket = UnixSocketChannel.open(socketAddress).socket()
val inputStream = socket.inputStream
val reader = inputStream.bufferedReader()
while (true) {
    val line = reader.readLine()
    println(line)
}
```

Where do I "put" the http://localhost/events ? The above code just blocks on reader.readLine(). Any suggestion about how to read events? Please note that I'm not forced to use JNR. It just seemed like the best option but I'm open to alternatives.

Comment: You need to implement the HTTP protocol, sending a `GET /events` request to the socket, then parsing the response.

Comment: I don't know Kotlin, but maybe there's a library you can use for this.

Comment: well if it works n java then that library can be used in kotlin, or idea can convert java code into kotlin code (that is written like java)
and there seems to be a java api for docker.. i hope this does what you need it to do https://www.baeldung.com/docker-java-api

Comment: Thanks to the both of you, originally I discarded docker-java but upon further reading it does suit my needs.